# Java Robot class not working with installation

Tags: java, awtrobot

```
Robot r = new Robot();

String command = "C:\\Users\\xyz xyz\\Desktop\\JavaProg\\kmp.exe";

         //Run setup file 
Process run =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"" + command+ "\"");

    r.delay(4000);  
    r.mouseMove(0, 0); //not working if I run kmp.exe but work with notepad.exe
    r.delay(2000);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R); //It should chose Russian language but not 
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
```

I am using Robot class to automate a installation package.Code is opening the kmp setup, the default security warning of win 8 as I have disabled, but then mouse should move to 0, 0 coordinate yet it is not moving. Same time if instead of "kmp.exe" I run "Notepad" then notepad will open and mouse will also move to 0, 0.

Does it have anything to do with kmp.exe installation package as it is fetching the control from java program or something like this.